# how to call other file method using separate route file in node js

Tags: node.js, routes, middleware

//server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8888;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
const userList = require("./public/model/api/userList");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/user',userRoutes);
app.use('/admin',adminRoutes);
app.use('/userList',userList);

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("server is runing on port:",PORT);
})
```

//route file  ,admin.js

```
const express = require("express");
const reqFilter = require('../public/model/middleware');
const app = express();
const route = express.Router();


var userData = require('../public/model/api/userList');

route.use(reqFilter);
app.post("/users",(req,res)=>{
    console.log("no 1");
    res.send({data:"Admin get user is here!"});
});

route.post("/list",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(userData.userlist);
    res.send({data:"Admin post user is here now!"});
});


app.use('/',route);
module.exports = app;
```

//other file ,,, userList.js

```
exports.userlist = function(req,res){
    res.send("this is userlist");
}
```

//errore -> TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

what is the problem please help me to solve this...

i have a problem with separate route from separate folder.. and dont call other file method using separate route ..

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing `reqFilter` correctly. You need to change

```
const reqFilter = require('../public/model/middleware');
```

to

```
const { reqFilter } = require('../public/model/middleware');
```

or

```
const middleware = require('../public/model/middleware');
route.use(middleware.reqFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Router.js

```
import userList from "./userList";
import mymiddleware from "./mymiddleware";

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(mymiddleware, createTransaction);

module.exports = router;
```

userList.js;

```
    exports.userlist = function (req, res) {
      Users.findOne({})
        .then((users) => {
          res.status(200).json(users);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          next(error);
        });
    };

export default getTransaction;
```